# how to send a exposed filter when use Service views

Tags: services

I create a exposed filter of field `field_nick_name`.

and I visit this link

```
http://drupal/daxuebao/api/views/user_search_by_nick?filters[field_nick_name]=a
```

and this link

```
http://drupal/daxuebao/api/views/user_search_by_nick?field_nick_name=a
```

this above 2 can not work, is there someone can tell me how to use Service View with exposed filter?

Answer (score 0):

I try to find out the views setting that store in database with following code:

```
$db = db_select('views_display', 'v')
    ->condition('v.vid', '30')
    ->fields('v', array('display_options'));

  $res = $db->execute()->fetchAssoc();
  $a = unserialize($res['display_options']);
```

the `$a` contain a `filter` array. The `field_nick_name` actually is `field_nick_name_value`, and `uid` is `uid_raw`